# Sane View / Controller approach for multiple route action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new at ASP.NET MVC, and i have a question that may be plain simple for most of you, but I can't still figure out what should be the best approach.

So, i have a "Note" entity, a Note controller (with standard Index, List, Create, Edit, Delete actions) and a Note View. Talking about the List action, this may be "invoked" from different sources. Examples: i have a Project, which has a couple of notes attached to it, and i have a User, that is who create this Notes.

I have 4 (more, but let's say 4) scenarios:

1. List ALL notes
2. List notes FOR a certain project
3. List notes FROM a certain user
4. List notes FOR a certain project FROM a certain user

The result lists are almost similar, except for some columns that may be hidden in some cases (and context menus, etc.. but figuring out how to set up this i think i can handle it well).

i.e.

Case 1

*Id     Reason     Amount     Project     User*

Case 2

*Id     Reason     Amount     User*

Case 3

*Id     Reason     Amount     Project*

Case 4

*Id     Reason     Amount*

This is pseudo-code for the List action

```
        public ActionResult List(int? proj_id, int? user_id)
    {
        int requestType = proj_id.HasValue ? 1 : 0;
        requestType += user_id.HasValue ? 2 : 0;

        switch (requestType)
        {
            case 0: //no parameters
                return View(getNotes());
                break;
            case 1: //filter by project
                ViewData[ViewDataConst.VIEW_HIDE_COLUMN_PROJECT] = true;
                return View(getNotesByProject(proj_id));
                break;
            case 2: //filter by user
                ViewData[ViewDataConst.VIEW_HIDE_COLUMN_USER] = true;
                return View(getNotesByUser(user_id));
                break;
            case 3: //filter by project and user
                ViewData[ViewDataConst.VIEW_HIDE_COLUMN_PROJECT] = true;
                ViewData[ViewDataConst.VIEW_HIDE_COLUMN_USER] = true;
                return View(getNotes(proj_id, user_id));
                break;
        }

    }
```

And in related List view i have something like

```
     @if (!ViewData[ViewDataConst.VIEW_HIDE_COLUMN_PROJECT]) 
     { 
        <th> Project Name </th>
     }
```

My question is: is this approach correct? Or is it a complete WTF?
Should i have multiple views that handle different columns? Even if the behavior is practically the same?  Multiple controllers? Is ViewData pure evil? :)

Any reply, advice, proposal of incarceration is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should ask yourself a question: What's the benefit of putting it all in one action?

I personally can't see one. Moreover with your approach there is that awful switch that can grow and grow until it explodes sometime :). Also 2 **optional** parameters that can be a pain while debugging.

My advice is to create a separate action for each scenario like:

1. ListForProject(int id)
2. ListForUser(int id)
3. ListAll()
4. ListFor(int userId, int projectId)

From each of the actions you can return exactly the same view:

```
return View("SharedViewName", yourNotes);
```

You can also build your views from partials and than each of the actions would have it's own view that would only put suitable partials in suitable places. This way there will be much less 'ifs' in your view - the less 'ifs' in a view the better.

Speaking of ViewBag / ViewData, they are helpful sometimes, but generally it's much better to wrap the data for your view in a simple ViewModel class.

Comment: I see. But my idea was to have something like /Projects/1/Users as well as /Projects/1/Notes etc. In this way do i have to write routes for any scenario?

Comment: @AlbertoA Yes, in case you want to have meaningful routes, you'll have to  write individual routes. You may encounter a problem a problem with ListFor(int userId, int projectId). You'll probably have to do something like this:  /Projects/<project_id>/User/<user_id>/Notes. If you try hard, you probably will be able to make the routes a little generic, but this may be quite a lot of work and will be a hell to debug.